# How to debug Standalone expo App in android device

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, expo

I am quite new to react/Expo, I have built an android bundle with `expo build:android`

now the APK I got is in production mode hence I can not debug it in my chrome dev tool. The problem is I am getting an issue in standalone build only while the development feature was working fine.
Is there any way I can build an expo app in development mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AS It has been five months AND there is no reply, I would like to share the approach that I took for this issue.
In the expo, you can switch on/off production mode, in production mode, you can debug and log there this would be the same app running after the standalone build, I think 99% problems would be fixed by this. In some special cases like (for example-  notification key, Keystore files) you will have to look for their particular support pages. Let me know if anyone facing still facing issues after the above steps  I would surely try to help.

Comment: If you can provide the steps you followed it would be great. I just want to generate a debug-apk for my app. What should I do?

Comment: As for I know , via expo we can not generate apk's in debug mode . Although we can debug app in production environment with debug mode(option given just above expo QR code). Also I dont think you would need debug APK . This should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks.. I think expo should bring that option of generating a debug-apk soon. While sharing links is fine. It makes no sense asking to install an expo app first to install my application. However, that feature is amazing while you want to push live updates to the testers.

Comment: I am not getting logs even on production mode

Comment: Please share mode details, logging is very straight forward in expo